# Adding a CNAME entry to a naked domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns, cname

I'm using Amazons AWS certificate manager to create some SSL/TLS certificates for a domain.

I want three variants of the domain name covered by the certificate:

1. Standard domain
2. Naked domain
3. Wildcard domain (for sub domains etc)

I need to validate these domains via a DNS update. Specifically a CNAME update. My DNS configuration is currently with GoDaddy and pointed to AWS via an A-record.

I've added the CNAME name and value for the standard domain verification and this went through as expected, however I have no idea how to update the naked and wildcard variants.

[image]

Comment: You can not add a CNAME at apex (what you call a naked domain) as this record is incompatible with any other one, and the apex already has at least SOA and NS records.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek the question doesn't clearly state the nature of the issue. The CNAME that is needed is not at the domain apex. Amazon Certificate Manager can do domain validation (prior to issuing a certificate) by giving you a special CNAME which, once created, allows the CA to confirm your control of the domain and thus your authorization to have the certificate issued. It isn't clear what problem is being encountered here, since one of them appears to have worked... but ACM *may* have a constraint that only a single SAN/UC cert per domain can be validated with this mechanism. Investigating.

Comment: What is a "special CNAME"? There are CNAMEs in the DNS protocol, a "special CNAME" is outside of it.

Comment: No, @PatrickMevzek not a special kind of CNAME.  It's CNAME with a *specially-crafted value*, e.g. `_string-of-hex-digits.example.com CNAME _another-hex-string-here.acm-validations.aws.`  The values are opaque and not sensitive, but the presence of the record is used to validate your request for an SSL certificate (by validating that you indeed control the domain) and the values are given to you when the cert is requested.  This is a common practice among CAs for DV certs.  It is not a CNAME at the apex even when it's for a certificate for the naked domain.  It's an ordinary, valid record.

Comment: @Michael I was just quoting you: "by giving you a special CNAME" you wrote. What you describe is not a "special" CNAME. It is just a CNAME, not at apex, obviously. And I am aware on how validation work, thanks.

Comment: @Dan382 my comment about a possible limitation of one cert per domain is based on an ambiguity in the documentation that further investigation reveals not to be the case, so that is not the issue.  If you look at the two "pending" records, they should be showing the same CNAME record and all you should have to do is create it.  It is possible that you have pasted too much or not enough, depending on how much of the value the Go Daddy UI expects you to supply and how much is implicit.  These values are not sensitive, so can you show us a screen shot from the Go Daddy console?

Comment: @Michael, sure no problem. Given that I don't need the certificate for the core domain (www.my4seasons.com), should I try and restart the certification process with AWS without this domain as it'll already be covered by the wildcard anyway (as pointed out by @Sudo)? https://ibb.co/hPHrPm

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot as mentioned the CNAME records for the apex and wildcard are identical https://ibb.co/i3jo4m.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, not related to DNS validation, *.my4seasons.com will protect www.my4seasons.com. So you can request the certificate for the apex domain my4seasons.com and the wildcard domain *.my4seasons.com .

Now, the DNS CNAME and value for the apex domain and wildcard domain should be [same](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-validate-dns.html) and you should add the CNAME and the value for these same as another record in GoDaddy as you did for www.my4seasons.com .

Comment: Thanks @sudo. Not sure if it'll work as is or if I'll have to redo as *.my4seasons.com as the core domain (with www.my4seasons.com removed). If I delete them am I able to simply re-add them again or will I hit an error due to the initial failed attempt?

Comment: No, that should work fine @Dan382.  ACM should give you the same CNAME records again.